# Does TDD end up with pure value objects and pure manipulators/controllers?

Tags: design-patterns, tdd

I am gettting more and more into TDD, and it seems to me all my classes usually end up being pure data holders, or pure data manipulators. Is this the expected outcome of TDD? Or am I taking a too extreme approach?

Comment: No. Why would it? I guess it's just that you're doing the typical service-based enterprise application. Other kinds of applications or libraries can use TDD, and have a different architecture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TDD does mean you will tend to write code with fewer dependencies. Which in turn means that classes tend towards having a single responsibility. Which may manifest its into having simpler classes as you've described. It doesn't necessarily have to end up that way but by mercilessly refactoring you approach that, certainly.